# O(log n) index update and search

Tags: c++, time-complexity, stdmap

I need to keep track of indexes in a large text file.  I have been keeping a `std::map` of indexes and accompanying data as a quick hack.  If the user is on character 230,400 in the text, I can display any meta-data for the text.

Now that my maps are getting larger, I'm hitting some speed issues (as expected).

For example, if the text is modified at the beginning, I need to increment the indexes after that position in the map by one, an O(N) operation.

What's a good way to change this to O(log N) complexity?  I've been looking at [AVL Arrays](http://avl-array.sourceforge.net/), which is close.

I'm hoping for O(log n) time for updates and searches.  For example, if the user is on character 500,000 in the text array, I want to very quickly find if there is any meta data for that character.

(Forgot to add:  The user can add meta data whenever they like)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more background?  While the question itself is easy enough to follow, I feel like if we knew more about the actual problem you are trying to solve, a better overall solution may present itself.  Such as, can you not store metadata inline with the item, rather than having to use the layer of indirection of the index?

Comment: Chad:  I cannot modify the original text, so no inline metadata.  I could have a 500,000 character text document with 100,000 metadata points in my std:map.  The metadata is not displayed inline with the original text either, but in a separate window.

Comment: Without modifying the original text -- so you have a plain text (ASCII or similar) file?  When you read in the data, instead of reading in the characters, read each character and create a structure that holds the character representation and any necessary metadata.  In memory you have complete control, right?  You can write the "unmodified" characters back out, and potentially write the metadata to some other file/location.

Comment: yes, but memory usage would go through the roof if each character had a meta data block attached to it.

Comment: If each character held a pointer to a metadata block, then 1M characters is only ~63MB given a 64bit pointer.  If the characters actually _have_ metadata, then the size will need to be used anyway.

Comment: 63 MB can be quite a bit on say... an iPad.  That's a ways away though, so I may be leaning that way.

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Make a binary tree of offsets.

The value of any offset is computed by traversing the tree from the leaf to the root adding offsets any time a node is a right child.

Then if you add text early in the file you only need to update the offsets for nodes which are parents of the offsets that change. That is say you added text before the very first offset, you add the number of characters added to the root node. now one half of your offsets have been corrected. Now traverse to the left child and add the offset again. Now 3/4s of offsets have been updated. Continue traversing left children adding the offset until all the offsets are updated.

@OP:

Say you have a text buffer with 8 characters, and 4 offsets into the odd bytes:

```
the tree:              5
                      / \
                     3   2
                    / \ / \
                    1 0 0 0
sum of right
children (indices) 1  3 5  7
```

Now say you inserted 2 bytes at offset 4. Buffer was:

```
01234567
```

Now its

```
0123xx4567
```

So you modify just nodes that dominate parts of the array that changed. In this case just 
the root node needs to be modified.

```
the tree:              7
                      / \
                     3   2
                    / \ / \
                    1 0 0 0
sum of right
children (indices) 1  3 7  9
```

The summation rule is walking from leaf to root I sum to myself, the value of my parent if I am that parent's right child.

To find if there is an index at my current location I start at the root and ask is this offset greater smaller than my location. If yes I traverse left and add nothing. If no I traverse right and add the value to my index. If at the end of traversal my value is equal to my index then yes there is an annotation. You can do a similar traverals with a minimum and maximum index to find the node that dominates all the indices in the range, finding all the indices to the text I'm displaying.

Oh.. and this is just a toy example. In reality you need to periodically rebalance the tree otherwise there is a chance that if you keep adding new indices just in one part of the file you will get a tree which is way out of balance, and worst case performance would no longer be O(log2 n) but would be O(n). To keep the tree balanced you would need to implement a balanced binary tree like a "red/black tree". That would guarantee O(log2 n) performance where N is the number of metadatas.

Comment: I thought of using offsets, but calculating the index of a node in a tree would be o(N) again, since, I'd have to add the offsets of all the notes ahead of it.  Also insertion near the front would be fast, but near the end would require adding the offsets up to that point, which would be o(N) again.

Comment: No. It is a tree of offsets. To calculate any index, you traverse the tree from leaf to root. So if you had 1024 indices, it would take you 10 node traversals to compute the index. O(log2 n) Likewise to insert text anywhere in the file will similarly be O(log2 n).

Comment: Maybe I'm getting a brain f*rt here, it's been a long day, but I'm not getting it.  If it's offsets, it's either offsets from the beginning of the file (indices) or offset from the last metadata (full tree traversal).

Comment: I wondered if this has a name, so I poked around on Wikipedia. It looks this is a special case of an enfilade (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enfilade_%28Xanadu%29).

Comment: Okay, I got it, I think.  Now the user adds a new metadata point at index 5.  Inserting the index into the tree will get a really unbalanced tree fairly quickly,
`
       7
      / \
     5   2
    / \ / \
   3  0 0  0
  / \
 1   0
`
So I would have to figure out when to insert an index and when to insert an offset, or when balancing the tree, do some extra math.

(can't seem to get code display working)

Comment: @RafaelBaptista sorry, didn't see your comment about rebalancing the tree.  The rebalance would become a pain, since some of the data is the actual index, and some is offsets.

Comment: Yeah. Basically thats it. I'd start by implementing or finding a red/black tree. And then use it to hold these offsets on the RB tree nodes. You'll need to recalculate offsets when the RB tree rebalances. But that update will also be O(log2 n) in the worst case.

Comment: I'll work on it this weekend to see how much of a nightmare the balancing will be.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista I can't get the balancing right.  Converting from index to offsets is a pain.  I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store indices!  There's no way to possibly do that and simultaneously have performance better than `O(n)` - add a character at the beginning of the array and you'll have to increment `n - 1` indices, no way around it.

But if you store substring lengths instead, you'd only have to change one per level of tree structure, bringing you up to `O(log n)`.  My (untested) solution would be to use a [Rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) with metadata attached to the nodes - you might need to play around with that a bit, but I think it's a solid foundation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I used a rope for a bit, but since my 'resolution' is in individual character, my rope nodes were characters as well, and I wasn't seeing any great speeds.

Using substring lengths will also give me O(n) on searches near the end of the text.

Comment: @user1475524 - Your metadata is applied to individual characters, then?  'Cause otherwise any run of characters with the same metadata (or lack thereof) could be grouped into a single rope node.

Comment: @user1475524 - Ouch!  Scratch that, then.  I'll let you know if I come up with anything else - it is kind of a cool problem - but 'til then... Good luck!